# Why does my char array return different characters for each index in C

Tags: c, string

I have a string, which I declare as char myStr[ ] = "5.3 2.4 1.8".

When I print it directly with printf, it seems to print what I would expect. However, when I print each index, instead of getting myStr[3] = ' ' , I get myStr[3] = 32. Below is my code and output. I would like to know why this is happening, and how I can ensure that the spaces will be interpreted as space and not the number 32?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int words(char myStr[ ]);

int main(){
char myStr[ ] = “5.3 2.4 1.8”;
printf(“myStr is: %s\n", myStr);
words(myStr);
}

int words(char myStr[ ]){
  int i, length, count=0, prev=0;
  length= strlen(myStr);

   printf("The length of myStr is: %d\n", length);

  for (i=0; i<length; i++){
   printf("The %d letter of myStr is: %d\n", i, myStr[i]);
   if (myStr[i] != ' '){
      if (prev=0)
        count++;
      else
        prev=1;
    }
    else
      prev=0;
  }
  return count;
}
```

Below is the output:

```
The first line is: 5.3 2.4 1.8
The length of myStr is: 11
The 0 letter of myStr is: 53
The 1 letter of myStr is: 46
The 2 letter of myStr is: 51
The 3 letter of myStr is: 32
The 4 letter of myStr is: 50
The 5 letter of myStr is: 46
The 6 letter of myStr is: 52
The 7 letter of myStr is: 32
The 8 letter of myStr is: 49
The 9 letter of myStr is: 46
The 10 letter of myStr is: 56
```

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: Use `%c` to interpret it as a character instead of `%d` which will print the ASCII value of the character. Also change `if (prev=0)` to `if (prev==0)`. `=` is the assignment operator, and is different from `==`, which is the comparision operator.

Comment: To print a character, use `"%c"` as the format specifier.

Comment: 32 is the ASCII (Unicode) value for space or blank.  Just like the digits have values between 48 and 57, blanks are 32 and decimal points are 46.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cause each `char` is stored as an 8-bit-width integer from the memory's perspective, according to [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/)

In `printf` use `%c` will get char and `%d` will get the int

e.g:

```
char a = 'A';
printf("%c\n", a);
printf("%d\n", a);
```

the output will be:

```
A
65
```

the piece of a's memory just like

```
        +-----------+                
    a   | 01000001  |                
        +-----------+
```

two different results just because the output format of `printf`

Comment: Thank you @simon_xia. One side question I notice is the line if (myStr[i] != ' '). For some reason, this evaluates for false each time, even though myStr is character type. So, when I run the int words() function, I get zero words, when I should get 3 (since there are two spaces in myStr "5.3 2.4 1.8"). Do you know how I could get my program to recognize myStr[3] as a ' ' , so that the statement if (myStr[i] != ' ') will evaluate to true twice, and return a word count of three? Many thanks again...

Comment: @user2808302 the `mystr[i] != ' '` is working correctly. You're probably confused because `if (prev=0)` doesn't do what you think it does

Comment: @user2808302    the statment `if (prev=0)` should be `if (prev==0)`

Comment: PS: It's a good practice to use `int words(char *myStr);` instead of `int words(char myStr[ ]);` @user2808302

Answer (score 1):

If we look at the [table of format strings](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) for `printf()`, we see that if we want to print an integer we would use `%d`. You claim that you would like to print a character. Which is `%c`.

So, let's fix your call to `printf()`:

```
printf("The %d letter of myStr is: %c\n", i, myStr[i]);
```